# Apply function over numpy arrays without looping

Tags: python, numpy

1. So we can do this in with numpy arrays:

   ```
   IN:
    a = np.array([1,2,3])
    b = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,4], [1,2,5]])
    a+b
   OUT:
     array([[2, 4, 6],
            [2, 4, 7],
            [2, 4, 8]])
   ```
2. I have this function, where di and dj are lists or arrays of the same lenght and KL is scipy.stats.entropy

   ```
   def dis(di,dj):
       di = np.array(di)
       dj = np.array(dj)
       m =  0.5 * (di+dj)
       kl1 = KL(di,m)
       kl2 = KL(dj,m)
       return 0.5*(kl1+kl2)
   ```
3. I was wondering if there was a way to apply the function as with a+b:

   ```
   dis(a,b)
   ```

So instead of doing:

```
 for x in b:
     dis(a,x)
```

I am getting this error when trying to run:

```
    dis(a,b)
```

[image: Error]

**UPDATE** After resolving the error thanks to hpaulj suggestion I get the following result:
Result [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWIwY.png)

The problem with the result is that KL should only give positive values. So I don't get quiet well what does:
        dis(a,b)
is actually doing.

Comment: What is the error you get when you try to run `dis(a, b)`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Kevin, I updated my question with a link to the picture of my error.

Comment: The code in the error is not the one you show.  Do you understand the error?  It has to do with that `float` call, not any looping or broadcasting issues.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Understood. Nevertheless, the output I get doesn't make sense. I updated my question with a picture of my result

Comment: Just a note on performance, you can use `np.asanyarray` in place of `np.array`, and it will speed up your code substantially when the inputs are already arrays.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking forward to make my code more efficient too. :)